# Checkbox inside an anchor click behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, event-bubbling

Consider following snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <a id="a" href="http://google.com">Goooooogle</a>
        </form>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                var checkbox = $('<input type="checkbox"></input>');
                checkbox.prependTo($('#a'));
                checkbox.click(function(e) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    // do something useful
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to get a checkbox inside `<a>`, and get following on-click behavior:

1. Toggle check mark normally as usual
2. Do something useful like AJAX-request
3. Stay on this page, i.e. not be redirected to an `a href`

Also I want to not override default behavior if I click anywhere in `a`, but not on checkbox. I.e. I want to allow to execute all event handlers associated with `a` click itself.

I thought that should be pretty easy, but I can't get desired behavior. Either:

- I get redirected to Google if I put a code provided.
- I don't get check mark toggled if I use `e.preventDefault()` of `return false;`. Furthermore in that case checkbox ignores explicit `checkbox.attr('checked', 'checked')` and all other possible ways to set the check mark.

Where is the catch?

*UPD:* This works as expected in Chrome, e.g. I'm not redirected on click, but fails in Firefox. Is there cross-browser way?

Comment: why do you want to put the checkbox inside the anchor tag? What is the desired outcome?

Comment: This is an oversimplified version of what I have to deal with. I can't do it in html. In any case, does it change something?

Comment: There is probably another way to achieve what you want to do. But we don't know what you want to do

Comment: [Something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/eqaG7/)?

Comment: @nailxx looks like you've got your answer

Comment: @Shef No, try to click checkbox. This violates (3)

Comment: @LeePrice and all up-voted: I make a complex ui-control that transforms big nested list with anchors (needed for graceful degradation) to a drill-down menu. Each item could be either selected (using checkbox) or drilled down to show nested list. I.e. 2 different actions. Component user must not bother about checkboxes, obviously. Also I don't want to increase DOM's and CSS's size 3 times only to place the checkbox next to a in a new div. Should I provide all 1500 loc to make the problem more clear?

Answer (score 5):

Well, it looks like a known [Firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=62151), which leads to following link on checkbox click regardless of handlers' code. As a bit dirty workaround one can use:

```
var checkbox = $('<input type="checkbox"></input>');
checkbox.prependTo($('#a'));
checkbox.click(function(e) {
    setTimeout(function() { checkbox.prop('checked', !checkbox.prop('checked')); }, 10);       
    // do something useful on clicking checkbox and but not surrounding link
    return false;
});
```

Comment: If this is a Firefox bug, I think it's also a Chrome bug. I had react at the time but still.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question but some may still be curious since it was never really fully answered without a messy hack or workaround. All you have to do is simply check where the event's target originated.

So using your example ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YqY3f/2/)):

```
// Don't change pages if the user is just changing the checkbox
$("#a").click(function(e) {
    //e.preventDefault(); // Optional if you want to to keep the link from working normally

    alert("Click came from: " + e.target.tagName);
    if (e.target.tagName != "INPUT") {
        // do link
        alert("Doing link functionality");
    } else {
        // do something useful
        alert("Doing checkbox functionality");
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work - clicking on the checkbox still takes you to Google.

Comment: @Gaz It works great. You can see it working on the linked jsfiddle. Did you uncomment the line that says "if you want to keep the link from working normally"?

Comment: apologies you seem to be right.  Except to meet the question's needs the e.preventDefault() needs to only be in the "checkbox" bit. http://jsfiddle.net/YqY3f/8/

Comment: @Gaz that doesn't really work either, the checkbox becomes unchecked again after the alerts

Comment: Just move the e.preventDefault() into the link functionality if you don't want it to go somewhere. The checkbox will be checked when you click on it. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/lifz/hmb6po9y/5/

Answer (score 4):

I Know this question is over 5 years old, but I had the same issue recently and the work-around I found was to add an onclick function to the checkbox and in that function call event.stopImmediatePropagation().

from w3schools: "The stopImmediatePropagation() method prevents other listeners of the same event from being called"

ie...the anchor.

```
function checkbox_onclick(event){
event.stopImmediatePropagation(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a modified script

```
var checkbox = $('<input type="checkbox"></input>');
var a = $('#a');
a.unbind("click").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    checkbox.attr('checked', !checkbox.attr('checked'));
});
checkbox.prependTo(a);
checkbox.click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // do something useful 
});
```

i unbind the click event on the `<a>` and rebind it with a event to check/uncheck the checkbox and also prevent the default.

Comment: It does absolute inverse of what I want: it goes to Google when I click on checkbox, but it suppresses redirect when I click on the link text.

Comment: ehh that's weird. check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/manuel/Br8jM/ what is wrong with this?

Comment: The same: click on checkbox and you're redirected. Firefox Ubuntu 7.0.1

Comment: @nailxx I don't get redirected!