# Can't prevent click from propagating past checkbox to parent <a> in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm adding a checkbox inside a link with a user-script (Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey/etc.) and I don't want the link to be followed when the checkbox is clicked. This works without any `stopPropagation()` or `preventDefault()` in Chrome (surprisingly) but I can't get it to work in Firefox.

I tried 3 approaches, the desired behavior in the simplified code below is that you can click the checkbox without the **Don't go here** scrolling into view but *with* the checkbox working as expected so you can uncheck and recheck it etc.

In the first approach I do `e.stopPropagation()`, this makes the most sense to me and I would expect the click-event to not reach the `<a>` element. No dice, **Don't go here** scrolls into view. The checkbox functions normally, you can uncheck and recheck and I get the `.checked` value `true`/`false` as expected.

In the second approach I changed it to `e.preventDefault()`, this stops the link from being followed to the **Don't go here**-anker but also stops the checkbox from becoming visibly checked. Weirdly, its `.checked` property does return `true`, but you can't uncheck it, every time you click it it gives `true` but doesn't change to a checked checkbox visually.

Lastly, I put a `e.preventDefault()` on the onclick of the `parentNode`, since it's the parent's default click-behaviour I wanna stop. This yields the same broken checkbox as the second approach.

Tested in Firefox on both MacOS and Windows. Any insight welcome, including "this is indeed a Firefox bug without workaround" if that's the case.

Since I'm working on a user-script for an existing web-based tool so I'm somewhat restricted to the HTML that tool gives me. Answers like "don't put the checkbox inside the `<a>`" don't help me unfortunately.

```js
let $ = (id) => document.querySelector(id);

$('#stopProp').onclick=function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('#output').value+=this.checked + '\n';
}

$('#prevDef').onclick=function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#output').value+=this.checked + '\n';
}

$('#parentPrevDef').parentNode.onclick=function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName == 'INPUT') {
    $('#output').value+='preventing on parent!\t';
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}

$('#parentPrevDef').onclick=function(e) {
  $('#output').value+=this.checked + '\n';
}
```

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 23%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  left: -5px;
}

textarea, #scroller {
  width: 47%;
  float: left;
}

#scroller {
  height: 2em;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<a href="#dontgo"><input type="checkbox" id="stopProp"> stopPropagation()</a>
<a href="#dontgo"><input type="checkbox" id="prevDef"> preventDefault()</a>
<a href="#dontgo"><input type="checkbox" id="parentPrevDef"> parent.preventDefault()</a>
<a href="#stay">Reset test</a>
<textarea id="output" rows="10"></textarea>

<div id="scroller">
  <a name="stay">Stay here</a><br>
  <br>
  <a name="dontgo">Don't go here</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, the first thing I'd suggest is to not use `<a>` just to have something to hook some JavaScript into. `<a>` elements are for navigation - only use them for that. Instead, set the `click` events up on the checkboxes themselves, then you won't need any `preventDefault()` calls since checkboxes have no native behavior to prevent when clicked.

Comment: Next, consider just setting a single`click` handler up on a parent of all the checkboxes, let the event bubble up to that parent and then handle it there, based on what the `event.target` element was that triggered the event in the first place.

Comment: @ScottMarcus you've not read the code correctly, the click event-handlers are **already** on the checkboxes, not the `<a>`, those just have a `href` to an anker -> Navigation like they are intended for.

Comment: @asontu Regarding "Since I'm working on a user-script for an existing web-based tool so I'm somewhat restricted to the HTML that tool gives me. Answers like "don't put the checkbox inside the <a>" don't help me unfortunately ": if you're able to insert checkboxes into the links with JavaScript, you should also be able to insert them a siblings as well, or not?

Comment: @SebastianB. I can't position them properly when inserting as sibling to the `<a>` because multiple `<a>` elements have the same parent so then I lose the "connection" to the correct `<a>` that the checkbox pertains to.

Comment: This is an existing bug unfortunately open for 21 years:D
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=62151 This has solved it for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16437682/12475047