# Input checkbox inside an anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following structure in my html code. Due to unavoidable circumstances I can't change the html structure. I want both Link and the checkbox to be worked independently. How this can be done via Javascript or Jquery ?

```html
<a href="#">
  <span class="fa fa-chevron-right blue"></span> 
  Early Math
  <label class="label-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" data-field-type="checkbox"><i class="fa fa-2x icon-checkbox"></i>
  </label>
</a>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094483/checkbox-inside-an-anchor-click-behavior

Comment: This is not possible without amending the HTML, as your current structure is completely invalid; you cannot nest clickable elements (ie. the `label` and `input` inside the `a`)

Comment: Do you mean http://jsfiddle.net/0e294ax6/

Comment: @Mohammad just FYI, I cannot check that checkbox. This is the issue I was alluding to above

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Your right :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that a checkbox inside of an anchor can be made to work reliably. But even if you are unable to change the HTML directly, you can still manipulate it through Javascript/JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    $('a input').insertAfter("a");
});
```

(This does assume only one `<a>` tag and one `<input>` tag).